# map vs for-loop - whic is more performant (renders with react)

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, iteration

I have huge data, approximate 1000 objects in an array. Each object is containing minimum 20 fields (may be more than 20).

I have to iterate and manipulation with every field of each object of the array.

Currently, I'm using a for-loop, but it becomes very very slow. Sometimes it hangs and the browser become unresponsive.

What should be right way to iterate this much data? Could `map()` solve my performance problem?

Comment: Why don't create some experiments that fits your case at https://jsperf.com - that said if it comes out to manipulating DOM I'd say it doesn't matter if you use map or for-loop. 100 objects is insignificant. Your lag is likely caused by something else.

Answer (score -1):

use map function and create a setInterval function to load your data more in a intuitive way.